# How to run code in a custom appointment tab?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write an extension to my Outlook calendar - More specifically the appointment module. (Form designer)

I have a button in my designer, that I want to write some simple code around.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    msgbox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

The above code is put into the code editor that appears when I press "View code". Nothing happens.

How do I get a commandbutton to trigger a simple alert in the Outlook form designer?

Comment: What you have there should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom form script is now disabled by default. You can see more details for the known issue and you can re-enable it as the following [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-outlook-for-windows-ecf61305-f84f-4e13-bb73-95a214ac1230) suggests.

You can read more about that in the [Custom Form Security Changes](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/custom-form-security/) article

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much. I wonder why it's not explicitly stated in outlook...